# Moving aggregate within a specified date range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Using a sample credit card transactions data below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'card_id' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'date' : [datetime(2020, 6, random.randint(1, 14)) for i in range(5)],
    'amount' : [random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(5)]})

df
  
     card_id       date      amount
0       1      2020-06-07      11
1       1      2020-06-11      45
2       1      2020-06-14      87
3       2      2020-06-04      48
4       2      2020-06-12      76
```

I'm trying to take the total amount spent in the past 7 days of a card at the point of the transaction. For example, if card_id 1 made a transaction on June 8, I want to get the total transactions from June 1 to June 7. This is what I was hoping to get:

```
     card_id       date      amount     sum_past_7d
0       1      2020-06-07      11            0
1       1      2020-06-11      45            11
2       1      2020-06-14      87            56
3       2      2020-06-04      48            0
4       2      2020-06-12      76            48
```

I'm currently using this function and pd.apply to generate my desired column but it's taking too long on the actual data (> 1 million rows).

```
df['past_week'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x - timedelta(days=7))
def myfunction(x):
    return df.loc[(df['card_id'] == x.card_id) & \
                  (df['date'] >= x.past_week) & \
                  (df['date'] < x.date), :]['amount'].sum()
```

Is there a faster and more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `rolling` on `date` with `groupby`:

```
# make sure the data is sorted properly
# your sample is already sorted, so you can skip this
df = df.sort_values(['card_id', 'date'])

df['sum_past_7D'] = (df.set_index('date').groupby('card_id')
                        ['amount'].rolling('7D').sum()
                        .groupby('card_id').shift(fill_value=0)
                        .values
                    )
```

Output:

```
   card_id       date  amount  sum_past_7D
0        1 2020-06-07      11          0.0
1        1 2020-06-11      45         11.0
2        1 2020-06-14      87         56.0
3        2 2020-06-04      48          0.0
4        2 2020-06-12      76         48.0
```